# Why https api call is not working in axios for react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I fetch Data from API using http it works fine.But After SSL certification of the Server api,Webservices is not working after changing http to https.

it Gives me Network error on axios.

it works perfectly on ios but in android it gives me network error

any solution?

Comment: Please add some code to your post

Comment: i fetch the web api using axios i will not able to upload code

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: well i dont know that, but what if it is self signed?

Comment: i am having same issue any solution ?